What are some things to keep in mind while designing a binary planet system with a sun-like star?
My planets are both the same size as Earth, with about the same water:land ratio. They are tidally locked to each other, but not the star. I don’t know much about planets and orbits and other things like that, so I was hoping all of you could help me. The main thing I’d like to know is how it would affect the life on the planets. The days are 24 hours long, like Earth.

Please give us a specific problem. At the moment you are asking for a bit of everything, which is not our style of question

@L.Dutch, I edited it. Hopefully that’s better!

I added a key tag.

How what would affect the life on the planets? You have provided no data. For example, how far apart are the two sibling planets, which is the same thing as how long does it take for them to complete a revolution around the common center of mass, which is the same thing as how long is a day?

A note for some that may offer an answer for a question like this. The OP may not necessarily be asking for factors that may limit and bound their imagination. Which most often most answers default to.  Rather and maybe more importantly they may be asking for elements they may be unaware of that might provide an opportunity to enrich their creations.  2¢

The light/dark cycle would be different and the spots always facing each other would never get direct sunlight. So that would change a lot from terminology of day/night to plants.

@Mike: "Tthe spots always facing each other would never get direct sunlight": That of course depends very much on the specific geometry, which is not specified in the question. For example, if the two Earth-sized sibling planets are 80,000 km apart (to make them revolve once per day around their common center of mass), the angular size of one of them seen from the other will be only about 10°, so that the total eclipse at a point directly in line with the other planet will last about 40 minutes. I would say that 40 minutes is a much shorter time than "never".

@AlexP, the days are 24 hours long, like Earth. The reason I didn’t write that in my question is because I have absolutely no idea how that affects distance, etc. I can edit that in.

@ZonaC --- You've already got an answer, so please don't edit your question in a way that would invalidate any already existing answers!

For future reference, please remember the following. (a) Open-ended questions (like this one) are prohibited by the [help/dont-ask]. (b) Humanity has one and only one data point when it comes to life on a planet: Earth. How anything affects life on any other planet is mathematical speculation at best, pure fiction at worst. The only "realistic" answer anyone can have is what affects life on Earth. (c) Finally, remember per the [help/on-topic], our goal is to help you build your imaginary world. Thanks.

Rule of Cool

Worldbuilding is an Art, an art of the fantastic. The main thing you need to keep in mind is quite simply: is this a true representation of my imagination? As an artist, your main goal is not necessarily to provide a true-to-science place, as if you were God planning for such a planetary system given the parameters of natural laws and constants within the real universe.

Rather, your main goal is to provide a reasonably believable place, within the context of the universe you envision. Given that you have already established the nature of this place, a binary planet tidally locked with its twin but not with their star and supporting life, you've actually established its existence and its providence.

If you were to ask this community other questions about this planetary system, we would be obligated to accept the reality of its existence and use our own powers of reason and creativity to provide answers.

But as far as your stated question goes, the main thing you need to keep in mind is the creativity factor, and that comes ultimately from your own mind and your own heart!


This is one of the best answers of this site. Rule of Cool is oftentimes lost when it comes to Worldbuilding. It isn't a sin by any means, and we should embrace it way more than we do.

The problem with this answer is that it both answers every question ever asked in this site, and it renders it useless. Sure, the paper will stand whatever you want to write on it, but this site was created in order to help writers not to stretch the suspension of disbelief of their target audience too far. Saying "write what you think is cool and don't worry about its plausibility" is a valid answer for Writing.SE, but it is antitheticalto everything this site stands for.
